# How to use timer to check if event is occurred in Corona SDK

Tags: android, sdk, coronasdk

I want to check if a object is invisible or not using timer but the code i am using is not working like i needed it.

here is the code i am using

```
    local function listener( event )
        print( "listener called" )
        if (ball.isVisible == false ) then
            ball.isVisible = true
            ball.x = stargate_b.x
            ball.y = stargate_b.y
        end
    end
    timer.performWithDelay( 1000, listener )
```

and i am using the print function to check whether it loops or not and it doesn't
it just prints only once when the program starts

i try to change the 1000 to 0 and 1 but nothing happens

any help please

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timers only run once by default. Try doing `timer.performWithDelay( 1000, listener, -1 )` instead.